# Weka POS tagging + tokenization

Tags: machine-learning, weka, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, pos-tagger

I'm  new to **Weka**. I am trying to sentimental classify movie reviews. The thing is, I can understand the StringToWord Vector which tokenizes and attributes the word occurrences. I want to add the Parts Of Speech tags also to the attribute vocabulary but I am getting stuck to how?

Has anyone tried this before?

Please, can you guide me?

P.S . I am using **OpenNLP** for POS tagging and **Weka J48 classifier** !!

Comment: have you uploaded a text file and then tokenize it in Weka?

Comment: Yup, I did . I used TextDirectoryLoader class for accessing my data in instances format and StringToWordVector or tokenization . Now , I cannot understand how to add POS tags for each tokenized attribute ?
I also tried counting word occurences by my own and created an ARFF file on my own but it gave me error IOException premature end of line ...

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error approach:

Do something like write the POStagged data into a text file and then do the word2vec. Then check the distance between a word and a POStag, nearest one is it's POS?

Then there would be a problem like adjacent tags distance **might** be same!

Or else you can use RegEx after that, definitely worth a try.

But do the first one and do share the results! :)